# Scaling up an image

Tags: c++

This does not segment fault, but it is not reading the pixels of the "original" file.

```
Image Image::scaleUp(int numTimes) const
{
        Image newImage(width*numTimes, height*numTimes);
        newImage.createImage(width*numTimes, height*numTimes);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(int inner_x = 0; inner_x < numTimes; inner_x++){
                    for (int inner_y = 0; inner_y < numTimes; inner_y++){
                        newImage.pixelData[x*numTimes+inner_x][y*numTimes+inner_y] = pixelData[x][y];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return newImage;
}
```

Solved now * (*except my image comes out in b/w)

Comment: By scaled up do you mean change the image size?

Comment: What you are currently doing is scaling the colour level (bighting or darkening) the image is that what your wanting?

Comment: Ugh, no. I need to scale the entire image via numTimes.
How do I access the size parameters to make the image larger?

Comment: @codefail: So are you looking for image resizing algorithms (things like nearest-neighbor, bilinear, bicubic...)? I doubt anyone here is going to implement one for your homework, but if you make it clear that's what you want I'm sure you'll get some good links at least.

Comment: @Jefromi: no, sorry, this is a hard project for me to ask about since there are so many files involved (2 .cpp files I am working on, 1 .cpp file that is main program, 2 .h files) and all pretty much depend on one another.

I am lost because I don't understand how to access the function/object that handles the size of the "original image"

The way I understand, I need to take the original image that is created, copy it, and then apply numTimes (the value the image is to be scaled-up by, called from main in the mainprogram .cpp)

Comment: @codefail: Right, but don't you have to implement that scaling up yourself?

Comment: Got the scaling "right" but it's not reading the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods in C++ have a pointer to the current object named `this`.  You can return a reference to the object with the following:

```
 // Note that we're now returning a reference with Image&
 const Image& Image::scaleUp(int numTimes) const
 {
     // ...
     return *this;
 }
```

Comment: But I cannot do this as the prototypes are pre-defined.

Comment: If the method is `const` then `this` is `const Image*` so you can't return `Image&`, only `const Image&`.

Comment: Just a general question guys:

if the question goes haywire (like this did) do I post a new question? Like from this, i strayed away and started working on a grayScale of the image..and have questions about that

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to make the colors brighter (multiplying them by `numTimes`). Is this what you want to do ?

If you want to return a copy of the image, you should make a copy before applying your transformation, then return the reference to that image. Perhaps your Image class already has a copy constructor you can use to get the copy (if not, you will have to add it or have another way of constructing the object).

I think this is what you want:

```
Image Image::scaleUp(int numTimes) const
{
    Image newImage = new Image(); // You might have a constructor to specify size so data is pre-allocated ? 

    // Your copy-and-scale code, but set data in newImage ....
    // Using copyAll here should be avoided, since it is just copying data 
    // that you will need to set again when doing the scaling.

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Shoot, you are right. Edited the post with the Copy function I have

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think what you are trying to do is apply a contrast filter (multiply each pixel by a value). If you want a brightness algorithm, instead of multiply, just sum.  On basic way to do it, as long you read each pixel is:

```
float contrast = 1.10; //Apply 10% contrast
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    {
        int temp = pixelData[x][y] * contrast;
        temp = temp > 255 ? 255 : temp; //it is always good to check if the result is in the range 0..255
        pixelData[x][y] = temp;
    }
 }
```

In the code above, I'm doing in in place, in the original image. These steps will be performed for each pixel. I'm also assuming you have 8bits pixel (0..255) for each channel (RGB).

I'm also assuming that x (column) points to one element of RGB space, say R, while x+1 points to G and x+2 points to B. This is a case where all pixels channel are adjacent in the memory

Comment: no, i had made a mistake. i am in fact trying to increase the size of the image, not anything with the color./